# load a text file (contains pages) into a schema without any delimiter in pig

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

My Text file contains lot of pages without any delimiter. A page contains some header and footer and data under columns. Pages doesn't have same no of columns. 
But the advantage is the first line of the file is same. 
I want to try this PIG. When I load the file. Its reading each line as a tuple.

```
 A = LOAD '/user/test_500.txt';
 B = GROUP A ALL;
 C = FOREACH B GENERATE CustomUDF(A);
```

I need help in writing the Custom UDF and load them into schema.

For your reference please find the text file. (Unable to upload image) and there are lot of spaces between them

```
 1Report Number: RXXXX  Detail******    Page:1

 Source prgm: XXX Sheet date: xx/xx/xxxx

 Job:YYYYYY  ***** Current Date: xx/xx/xxxx

 0ACCOUNT NO    ACCOUNTABLE PARTY    TC-TS     TRADE DATE    SHARES                   AS OF NAV PRICE          CURRENT PRICE

 -----------   -------------------  -------   ----------    ------------ ---------   ---------------------    --------------------

 ALPHA CODE    CUM DISC  PLAN ID    RC        BATCH  NO     GAIN(+) /LOSS(-)         AS OF NAV AMOUNT         CURRENT AMOUNT

 -----------   -------------------  -------   ----------    ------------ ---------   ---------------------    --------------------

 EXTERNAL NO             DEALER NO            REP NO        CONTROL NO

 ******* Data for each column in 3 lines ********

 <FOOTER> Total Count: ************
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: It might even be a better idea to write a custom load function to deal with this kind of input.

Comment: I tried using custom load function but it lead to lot of complications. Can you please help me with it.

Comment: Or even better, don't use PIG for that :) How many files do you need to process ? How big are they ?